# mysql select distinct *

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I'd rather post an image here, but it says that I don't have enough reputation to do it.
I tried to find something similar to my question, but there are to much "distinct" and "group by" to find something useful... "distinct *" in search gives the same, as "distinct"..

[Here is link to xlsx-file with table with source example data and table with desired result](http://www.filedropper.com/table_5)

Source example data - is a simplified result of some complex query.

---

The question is here:

I'd like to apply to this result of select some grouping, which gives query "select distinct * from table_below". 
But, this variant is not very good for performance reason. My original non-simplified table has about 4000 rows, and 10 columns. So, "select distinct *" takes 20 sec to give needed result.

To be clear, I want to make grouping by 4-th column, but within every "column_id", as shown in xlsx attached file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest that it is a good idea to include 4-5 rows of sample data in your question, instead of providing download links.

Comment: FYI: `SELECT DISTINCT *` generally does nothing different than `SELECT *` because you most likely have a primary key.

Comment: No, it has not one. You could see it, if you've opened attached file )

I added an index for first column, so performance is good now ( < 1 sec ). But I assume, there must be some more flexible or just other solutions? ...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write out the coloumn names. Could you try this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT coming_id, spare_id ,spare_sum, product_id
FROM Table
Order by coming_id, spare_id, product_id
```